# As can be adjusted in a WPF application developed to change the resolution?

Tags: wpf

I read about WPF and I have following concerns: Normally when we develop applications (in my case) try to work with percentages that automatically adjusts to changes in resolution.

Currently I am developing an application to wpf apreder together to manage its operation on a 1280 * 1024 and when I wanted to see would be a resolution of 1024 * 768 application does not comply with the new resolution.

This is an example of code AXML.

```
<Window x:Class="pedido"        
    WindowState="Maximized"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="pedido" 
WindowStyle="None" Name="VentanaPeido" Background="White" BorderThickness="2" AllowsTransparency="False">
<Window.Resources>      
    <Style x:Key="myHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Name="todo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1280" Height="1024">
    <Grid Background="Maroon" Name="grdInicio">
        <StackPanel Name="titulo" Width="1280" Height="214">
            <StackPanel Height="10">
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="tituloLogo" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="245" Height="150">
                    <Image  Name="logoAuto" Width="150" Height="148" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="765" Name="tituloLetras">
                    <Label  Height="67.5"  FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1" Name="Mensaje" FontSize="44" Foreground="White" Width="707.5" OpacityMask="Black">Mensaje</Label>
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Canvas.Top="180" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gold" Height="85" Name="NombreTienda" Width="565" OpacityMask="Black">Nombre Tienda</Label>

                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Background>
                <ImageBrush  x:Name="fondoTitulo" Stretch="Uniform">
                </ImageBrush>
            </StackPanel.Background>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

        <StackPanel Name="espacio1" Background="White" Height="12" Width="1280" VerticalAlignment="Top"></StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="panel" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1280" Height="800">
            <StackPanel Name="ticket" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="635" Height="1280">
                <ListView HorizontalAlignment="center" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Name="lvPedido"  Height="600" ItemsSource="{Binding}" FontSize="30" IsEnabled="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" IsTabStop="False" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="False" BorderBrush="Black" ItemStringFormat="center" Background="White" FontFamily="Arila" BorderThickness="5" Opacity="3" FontWeight="Bold">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <!--ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}"-->
                        <GridView ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False"  >

                        <GridViewColumn Width="60">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=cantidad}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="316">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=item}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                         </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="80">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Text="{Binding Path=moneda}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Width="150" >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=monto}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                <StackPanel   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20"></StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Margin="15"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="555" Height="150">
                    <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black" Height="50" Width="535" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Total"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="Monto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="80" Width="565" Height="100" Opacity="2" OpacityMask="Magenta" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Foreground="White">monto</TextBlock >
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <ImageBrush  x:Name="fondo1">
                    </ImageBrush>
                </StackPanel.Background>
            </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Width="10" Height="800" Background="White"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="imagenProducto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="635" Height="800">

            <StackPanel Name="Imagen1">
                <Image Name="itemP" Width="635" Height="299" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="2"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="Espacio" Background="White" Width="635" Height="10"></StackPanel>

              <StackPanel Name="Video" Width="635" Height="299" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <MediaElement Name="Promo" Stretch="Uniform" Width="635" Height="299" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" MediaEnded="Promo_MediaEnded"/>
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <ImageBrush  x:Name="videoPromo" Stretch="Uniform">
                    </ImageBrush>
                </StackPanel.Background>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="Imagen2" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="635" Height="299">
                <Image Name="itemS" Width="635" Height="299" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="2" Tag="true" />
           </StackPanel>
           <StackPanel.Background>
                <ImageBrush  x:Name="fondo2">
                </ImageBrush>
            </StackPanel.Background>
        </StackPanel>


        </StackPanel>

</StackPanel>
```

I am doing wrong things? There is a better practice?

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not understanding the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon,

After reading and analyzing code tutorials I came across a way to solve my problem using the  With its help you can get the contents of a window is adjusted according to the size or the same as in my case the resolution.

Never mind that it defines a fixed size of the objects (such as myself) the action seeks to bring up the window size.

The solution would be code:

```
<Window x:Class="pedido"        
    WindowState="Maximized"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="pedido" 
WindowStyle="None" Name="VentanaPeido" Background="White" BorderThickness="2" AllowsTransparency="False">
<Window.Resources>      
    <Style x:Key="myHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Name="todo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1280" Height="1024">
 <Viewbox>
      <......>
   </Viewbox>

</StackPanel>
```

If someone else gets a different solution or cleaner, go ahead write it

Comment: The VentanaPeido would stink in Portuguese. :-)